# Two audio outputs for two different applications

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, sound-card

I need some help. Everytime I try to record sessions with people I can never play Youtube videos like they want because my Windows sound decides not to use communications device properly.

I have two sound cards. I'm trying to FORCE windows to use my Avid Soundcard to play Youtube videos via Chrome and and EMU sound card to run Fl Studio.

I CAN make this happen, sometimes, but not directly. Windows chooses it. For example if I start FL than Chrome. Chrome will be my communications device and FL will be my main. That's fine. But it doesn't always work that way for some reason or another. Maybe it's because I have to switch cards and unplug, during a session, I'm not sure.

So I'm trying to find a way to force this to happen all the time. Rather than rely on Windows to choose it.

Any advice? Do I really have to install a third party program just to tell Windows which sound card to use with what application? I know how to change this with Windows Media Player but I am mostly speaking of Chrome and Spotify here. Non third party solutions if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can route different programs to different sound devices using [CheVolume](http://www.chevolume.com/); You have to pay for a license to use it, though ($20 USD).

[image: chevolume transfer example]